# How to display index number if variable is outside the main method

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, double

Edit: What would you have to do if there are two or more functions within in a method. what im having a problem with is that i need to return multiple variable from the maxminavg method and i dont know how to make it so each new variable carries the value from the maxminavg method to the main method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double max = 0d;
        double sum = 0d;
        double min = arr[0];
        double avg = sum / arr.Length;
        double avgrnd = Math.Round(avg, 2);
        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        int index3 = 0;

        string[] txt = File.ReadLines(@"c: \Users\Stark\Moisture_Data.txt").ToArray();
        double[] arr = txt.Select(Double.Parse).ToArray();

        print(arr);
        Console.WriteLine();
        maxminavg(arr, sum, max, min, avg);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Index(arr, max, min, avgrnd, index1, index2, index3);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void maximinavg(double[] arr, double sum, double max, double min, double avg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            sum += arr.Length;
            if (max < arr[i]) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
            if (min > arr[i]) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        avg = sum / arr.Length;

        Console.Write("\nMaximum value in array: {0}, Mimimum value {1}, average value {2}", max, min, avg);
    }

    public static void Index(double[] arr, double max, double min, double avgrnd int index1, int index2, int index3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (max == arr[i])
            {
                index1 = i;
            }
            if (min == arr[i])
            {
                index2 = i;
            }
            if (avgrnd == arr[1])
            { 
                index3 = i;
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\nMax index {0}, Min index {1}, avg index {2}", index1, index2, index3);
    }
```

Comment: Can you include this file c: \Users\Stark\Moisture_Data.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you not returning the function result to the variable max?

I would recommend not using void functions and returning the function result straight to the variable as below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double max = 0d;
    double sum = 0d;
    int index = 0;

    string[] txt = File.ReadLines(@"c: \Users\Stark\Moisture_Data.txt").ToArray();
    double[] arr = txt.Select(Double.Parse).ToArray();

    print(arr);
    Console.WriteLine();
    max = maximum(arr, sum, max);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Index(arr, max, index);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static double maximum(double[] arr, double sum, double max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
        sum += arr.Length;
        if (max < arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    Console.Write("\nMaximim value in array: {0}", max);
    return max;
}

public static void Index(double[] arr, double max, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (max == arr[i])
        {
            index = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So the return max means that the variable max contains the maximum value in the array? which allows the new max variable to be used in the index method.

Comment: yes, you are returning the value of the variable 'max' which you assigned within the maximum function. And you are assigning that returned value to the variable you defined outside of that function 'max'.

Comment: I can see how you are getting confused. This is to do with variable scope and function scope in c#. I suggest you do some reading on it as it can be quite a complex thing to get your head around, but once you do it will make complete sense :)

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variables used within the function is limited to only that function. So you should return value of max as suggested by sjdm.

Another way of doing this is using a ref keyword. e.g

In main method:

max = maximum(arr, sum, ref max);

Signature of maximum method:

public static void maximum(double[] arr, double sum, ref double max)